# Angular service overrides itself when called more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a chat component that have a hash id of that chat. All my api call's (done by the service) have a hash value. When I call my chat component twice, the service hash value of the first chat gets overwritten by the seconds chat.

```js
angular.module('testModule', [])
  .controller('testController', function(testService, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.init = function() {
      vm.hash = vm.hash();
      testService.setHash(vm.hash);
    }

    vm.getServiceHash = function() {
      vm.serviceHash = testService.hash;
    }

    vm.init();
  })
  .service('testService', function() {
    var testService = {
      hash: null
    };

    testService.setHash = function(hash) {
      testService.hash = hash;
    }

    return testService;
  })
  .directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: $("#test\\.html").html(),
      controller: 'testController',
      controllerAs: 'test',
      bindToController: {
        hash: '&',
      },
      scope: {}
    }
  });

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['testModule']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <test hash="'123'"></test>
    <test hash="'321'"></test>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">
    <p>
      <h2> Controller hash: {{test.hash}} </h2>
      <button type="button" ng-click="test.getServiceHash()">Get service hash</button>
      <h2> Service hash: {{test.serviceHash }} </h2>
    </p>
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Services are instantiated only once in Angular. If you need your service to serve more than one client (ie. two of your chat components) you'll need to adapt your service for that.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions @jjmontes?

Comment: This is a good use case for object orientation in Angular.  Each one of your hash calls to your 'service' can return a new JS object that will be dedicated to that particular client. In AJS, a 'service' is simply 'syntactic sugar' on top of a 'factory' and services are always singletons as mentioned.  Here is an example of how you can create an object factory in AJS:
http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2014/02/14/angularjs-services-inheritance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jjmontes noted in a comment, services are *singletons* in Angular. As such, they should not maintain any state unless that state applies to all consumers. For example, a common set of data that applies to all consumers can be retrieved once and then used by all rather than making a potentially expensive call again. However, any controller-specific data should be maintained in the controller and passed to the service on demand.

Specifically in your case, instead of setting the hash value on the service, you should pass it as a parameter to the service method that the controller instances call.

```
.service('testService', function() {
  var testService = {
  };

  testService.callService = function(hash) {
    // call an API or whatever, passing the hash
  }

  return testService;
})
```

Comment: Would it be wrong for me to use a class and create a new instance for every controller?

Comment: @GuilhermeReda I don't think it would be "wrong" necessarily. Depends on how you want to use it. Sounds like you basically want a view model. Which is a real thing with many uses.